# Supremum and Infimum of the multiple variable function

Tags: functions, supremum-and-infimum

I have a function 
$$F(t_1,t_2)=\frac{t_1^2a^2+t_2^2 b^2+2t_1 t_2ab}{t_1^2+t_2^2}$$
where $0\leq t_1\leq 1$, $0\leq t_2\leq 1$.
I know that there is no limit of the function when $(t_1,t_2)\to (0,0)$.
But I want to know, has this function supremum and infimum ?

Comment: No global maximum can be found, the minimum is $0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $(t_1,t_2)\not=(0,0)$,
$$F(t_1,t_2)=\frac{(t_1a+t_2 b)^2}{t_1^2+t_2^2}.$$
Then by the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) it follows that
$$0\leq F(t_1,t_2)\leq \frac{(t_1^2+t_2^2)(a^2+b^2)}{t_1^2+t_2^2}\leq a^2+b^2.$$
Now consider the sequence $(a/n,b/n)\to 0$. What is the limit of $F(a/n,b/n)$?

Comment: Thanks, I also want to know , is there e sequence for (t1,t2) for which the F approaches to the (a^2 + b^2)?

Comment: @QajikHakobyan Consider the point $(a,b)$.

Comment: I have a limit on (t1,t2)

Comment: now I want to know is there a sequence which approaches to (0,0) and for which F approaches to (a^2+b^2)?

Comment: Or I want to know the supremum of this function near point (0,0)

Comment: @QajikHakobyan See my edit.